# How can I get a unique set from two arrays that removes the second occurance of an item by a key's value, not the first like Lodash uniqueBy does?

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

So, if I have two arrays...

```
const arr1 = [ { id: 1: newBid: true } ];

const arr2 = [ { id: 1, newBid: false }, { id: 2, newBid: false } ];
```

I want to wind up with an array that is like this

```
[ { id: 1, newBid: false }, { id: 2, newBid: false } ]
```

BUT... I want the `{ id: 1, newBid: true }` to be from `arr1` and not `arr2`

I was using Lodash `uniqBy(arr1, arr2, ['id'])`, but it deletes the 1st occurance, not the 2nd

Comment: What happens if you swap arr1 and arr2 in your call to uniqBy?

Comment: Also is it possible to generalize the logic to pick between arr1 vs arr2 or vice versa?

Comment: You want `newBid: false` from 2nd occurrence but full object from 1st occurrence?

Comment: @GalacticCowboy, you called it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#mergeWith) `mergeWith` function.

```js
const arr1 = [{
  id: 1,
  newBid: true
}];

const arr2 = [{
  id: 1,
  newBid: false
}, {
  id: 2,
  newBid: false
}];

function customizer(firstValue, secondValue) {
  if(firstValue) 
      return firstValue;
  else
      return secondValue;
}

console.log(_.mergeWith(arr1, arr2, customizer));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: why not just _.merge(arr2, arr1)

Comment: @JoeWarner because as per question, output must consider element from first element in case of match and in `merge` it will consider element from second array

Answer (score 0):

I find using an object as a map to be the easiest way to deal with this kind of problems.

```
const arr1 = [ { id: 1, newBid: true } ];

const arr2 = [ { id: 1, newBid: false }, { id: 2, newBid: false } ];

const map = {};

function execute(array) {
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        const item = array[i];
        map[item.id] = item;
    }
}

execute(arr1);
execute(arr2);

console.log(Object.values(map))
```